# How deploy meteor on Phusion Passenger?

Tags: meteor

I deployed an application with meteor that works perfectly in development mode on Ubuntu 16.04 (see the development mode site hosted on Digital Ocean at http://207.154.233.6:3000).
To go into production mode I rented a VPS at LWS. On this host with the same platform Ubuntu16.04 and DNS "sosbailleur.com", I tried:
- the meteor.org (bundle) method: nothing on the screen
- with mup: it crashes lamentably,
- with phusion Passenger mode nginx: with address
Ip fall on the message nginx (it's OK for nginx) with the DNS "sosbailleur.com") I fall on the homepage of the host.
I do not have anything significant in the logs.
versions:
-meteor: 1.5.2.2
-nodeJs: 4.8.4
- mongodB: 3.2.15

Would someone have a solution?
thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In my experience mup is by far the best solution. It can be a little tricky to set up initially, but over time it is the easiest to use. Deploying new versions is super easy. If you can provide details of the "crashes lamentably", we may be able to help.

Either way, you need to provide exact details of what the error messages and your config files, or we don't have enough information to help you

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem.
Meteor Up is based on Docker plus I would like to use nginx as a reverse proxy on a VPS.
A version of Mup: meteor-passenger installs phusion-passenger in an automatic way but I prefer to use the manual mode.

In fact if in the error file "error.log" there is no error indicated I found another error file "error.log.1" which indicates an error that would be related to a wrong installation of mongoDB.
I have reinstalled the latest version of mongoDB (4.2) but I still get the same error.

Comment: You still haven't provided any details of the error(s) you are getting